# PHP: Escape HTML entities between some HTML tags

Tags: php, html, escaping

Let's say that I have HTML like this:

```
<p>demo &</p><p>test</p><ul><li><p>Some <p><i><b>test<b/></i> text: < 15 ( less than 15 ) </p></p></li></ul><p></p>
```

I need to escape special characters (like ", ', <, >, &, etc) but only between h1, h2, p, ul, ol, li and b tags. So the result should be:

```
<p>demo &amp;</p><p>test</p><ul><li><p>Some <p>&lt;i&gt;<b>test</b>;&lt;\/i;&gt; text: &lt; 15 ( less than 15 ) </p></p></li></ul><p></p>
```

Do you have any idea how to do this? I've tried using DOMDocument but I can't load this HTML, because is invalid. I've also tried preg replacing, but I think this is too complex to do this magic.

Comment: Please show your effort, so we can figure out where you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with the HTML as you point out, the furthest I've got so far is in fact too over eager and has a tendency to revisit text already processed.  You will also probably have a better method of encoding the strings, I've just used `htmlspecialchars` as it's east to try.

The code uses XPath to find the various node types your after and then looks at the text content below that, it won't solve all your problems, but may give you a starting point...

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html = "<p>demo &</p><p>test'\"</p><ul><li><p>Some <p><i><b>test</b></i> text: < 15 ( less than 15 ) </p></p></li></ul><p></p>";

$xml = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
$tags = $xp->query("//p | //li | //i | //b | //ul | //ol | //li" );
foreach ( $tags as $tag )   {
    echo $tag->tagName.PHP_EOL;
    $content = $xp->query("descendant::text()", $tag );
    foreach ( $content as $element )    {
        if ( $element instanceof  DOMText ) {
            echo "to:".htmlspecialchars($element->wholeText).PHP_EOL;
            $newTextNode = $xml->createTextNode( htmlspecialchars($element->wholeText) );
            $element->parentNode->replaceChild( $newTextNode, $element );
        }
    }
}

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Weird - your code gives me a warning: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1` and the code doesn't process further.

Comment: I've added `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` to the code, should ignore the error.